# Can't compile a TypeScript code that uses OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, typescript, openlayers

I have some simple TypeScript code that uses OpenLayers that I can compile into JavaScript, load into a browser and everything works fine:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()})],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```

However as soon as I try to import a second code file into the main file I get an error that I cannot resolve:

```
import {SomeClass} from "./SomeClass";

var map = new ol.Map({
  // ... save as above
```

`index.ts(3,15): error TS2686: 'ol' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.`

Compiling against OpenLayers types installed like so:

```
npm install --save-dev openlayers
npm install --save-dev @types/openlayers
```

How can I compile a TypeScript code base with multiple code files that uses OpenLayers?

Comment: According to [Github - OpenLayers](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers), ol needs installing as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
import * as ol from 'openlayers';
```